# Python: Lambda function

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Lambda functions and esp this one got me quite confused. I have a set of words that have an average length 3.4 and list of words = ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'lisa']

I want to compare the length of a word to average length and print out only the words higher than average length

```
average = 3.4
words = ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'lisa']

print(filter(lambda x: len(words) > avg, words))
```

so in this case i want

```
['hello', 'name', 'lisa']
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
<filter object at 0x102d2b6d8>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > avg, words)))
```

`filter` is an iterator in  python 3. You need to iterate over or call list on the filter object.

```
In [17]: print(filter(lambda x: len(x) > avg, words))
<filter object at 0x7f3177246710>

In [18]: print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > avg, words)))
['hello', 'name', 'lisa']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lambda x: some code
```

Means that x is the variable your function gets
so basically you need to replace `words` with `x` and change `avg` to `average` because there isn't a variable called `avg` in your namespace

```
print filter(lambda x: len(x) > average, words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have covered your problems with the lambda. Now this:

```
<filter object at 0x102d2b6d8>
```

This is your result. It is not an error; it is an iterator. You have to use it as a sequence somehow. For example:

```
print(*filter(lambda x: len(x) > average, words))
```

Or if you want it as a list:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > average, words)))
```

Comment: but this will not return a list

Comment: `print` won't return anything anyway. But if you want it as a list, just pass it to `list()`. I've added that example.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're wondering why there are contradictory answers being given here, note that in Python 2 you can do:

```
print filter(lambda x: len(x) > avg, words)
```

But as others have said, in Python 3 `filter` is an iterator and you have to iterate through its contents somehow to print them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have same variable in both sides of `:` operator.

```
lambda x:len(x) > avg
```

Here, `x` is the argument. This is equivalent to:

```
def aboveAverage(x):
    return len(x) > avg
```

only without `aboveAverage` function name.

Example use:

```
print map(lambda x:len(x) > avg, words)
```